# Is it possible to create folder name with property values in installer project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

In windows installer project, I need to create a folder under user's `Application Data` folder with the `Manufacturer` name and `ProductVersion`. Is this possible by referencing related property values? I tried using `[ProductVersion]` as folder name but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know you cannot do this with VS setup projects. However, there are other free tools, that integrate with VS, which can help you. Also, switching the tool might interest even more since starting with VS 2012 Microsoft has removed their support for setup projects, so you still need to look for an [alternative.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers)